# C++ String Comparison line.compare

Tags: c++

The program is getting one line and passing it into the IF statements fine, but it passes over each if statement.

If i change it to "if (line.compare("v"))" everything is added into the first vertex.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

```
string line;
    while(!myfile.eof())
     {
      getline (myfile,line);
      //stringstream line;
    if (line.compare("v"))
    {
        glm::vec3 vertex;
        (myfile,"%f %f %f\n", &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z );
        temp_vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }
    else if ( line.compare("vt") == 0)
    {
        glm::vec2 uv;
        (myfile, "%f %f\n", &uv.x, &uv.y );
        temp_uvs.push_back(uv);
    }
    else if ( line.compare("vn") == 0){
        glm::vec3 normal;
        (myfile, "%f %f %f\n", &normal.x, &normal.y, &normal.z );
        temp_normals.push_back(normal);
    }
    else if ( line.compare("f") == 0)
    {
     std::string vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
     unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
     (myfile, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2] );
     vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
     vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
     vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);
     uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[0]);
     uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[1]);
     uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[2]);
     normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[0]);
     normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[1]);
     normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[2]);
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots.  Post your actual code.

Comment: Sorry, i just wanted to add the debugger info in also.

Comment: What does compare return? Is the result different from the documentation? How is it different from what it says? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare

Comment: BTW, you can use the comparison operators with `std::string` instead of the `compare` method.

Comment: This line, `(myfile, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n"`, is missing a function identifier.

Comment: What's the difference between an *index* vector and an `indices` vector?

Comment: You may want to *transform* your string to lowercase before the comparisons.  Remember that the C++ language is case-sensitive, including string comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (line[1] == 't')
    {
        glm::vec2 uv;
        (myfile, "%f %f\n", &uv.x, &uv.y );
        temp_uvs.push_back(uv);
    }
```

This is now working for me, finding the specific character on the line.

I am having a problem where its saying Expression: string subscript out of range.

Comment: As i said, you have read to much data. Entire line. I have answered your problem already/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in

```
getline (myfile,line);
```

You must replace it with:

```
char cline[255];
myfile.getline(cline, 0xff, ' ');
string line(cline);
```

because you must process not by lines but by separate chars considering wavefront data format,  or specify string end char as `' '` by `myfile.getline(cline, 0xff, ' ');`.

Example of wavefront data.

```
# Wavefront OBJ file: C:\Documents and Settings\icastano\Desktop\teapot1
# Exported from Luxology modo on Mon Jul 07 16:09:46 2008
#

o Mesh

g default
v -3 1.8 0
v -2.9916 1.8 -0.081
v -2.9916 1.8 0.081
v -2.98945 1.66616 0
v -2.98117 1.66784 -0.081
v -2.98117 1.66784 0.081
v -2.97669 1.92024 -0.081
v -2.97669 1.92024 0.081
v -2.9688 1.8 -0.144
v -2.9688 1.8 0.144
v -2.95871 1.67241 -0.144
```

So if you do as you previously did (`getline (myfile,line);`), you will just read entire line for instance

```
v -2.98117 1.66784 -0.081
```

instead of proper `v` if you use `myfile.getline(cline, 0xff, ' ');`.

Which is not equal to either of your condition.

The conclusion use `getline` method with limiters to achive proper result.

Your fixed code is

```
    char cline[255];

    while(!myfile.eof())
     {
      // read limited line.
      myfile.getline(cline, 0xff, ' ');
      string line(cline);
    if (line.compare("v"))
    {
        glm::vec3 vertex;
        (myfile,"%f %f %f\n", &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z );
        temp_vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }
    else if ( line.compare("vt") == 0)
    {
        glm::vec2 uv;
        (myfile, "%f %f\n", &uv.x, &uv.y );
        temp_uvs.push_back(uv);
    }
    else if ( line.compare("vn") == 0){
        glm::vec3 normal;
        (myfile, "%f %f %f\n", &normal.x, &normal.y, &normal.z );
        temp_normals.push_back(normal);
    }
    else if ( line.compare("f") == 0)
    {
     std::string vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
     unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
     (myfile, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2] );
     vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
     vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
     vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);
     uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[0]);
     uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[1]);
     uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[2]);
     normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[0]);
     normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[1]);
     normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[2]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, i think i shouldn't jump the gun and ask people, i have sorted it. i'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Ill give it a go and see what happens also, i am interested in getting the best results for my time.

Comment: with myfile.getline(line, 0xff, ' '); . i get a error "error no instance of overloaded function" error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::getline(_Elem *,std::streamsize,_Elem)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *'

Comment: I tried it, but its cutting each line into pieces and only adding them into the vertex vectors. it doesn't go to the next else if statement. don't worry about it you have been a big help!